# How to save a BERT model after pretraining with official implementation on custom data in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, bert-language-model

I fine tuned the `bert_base_uncased` model on custom data by running `run_pretraining.py` from the [official](https://github.com/google-research/bert) implementation of bert. And this saved multiple `model.ckpt` files as usual.

But I want to save this model as a `.pb` file (also assets and variables) so as to load it as a `pytorch` model and use it for some task later. The issue is I'm unable to do it and neither am I able to find any helpful resource in doing so.

I have to use pytorch for the later task that I'm going to do. So, there could be two possible solutions to my problem:

1. How do I save a `.pb` file after fine tuning bert with official implementation? Or as I already have `model.ckpt`, how to convert this to a `.pb`?
2. How to pretrain bert with pytorch, so that I have what I want?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for BERT model implementation and later save model in .pb format.

```
# Bert layers
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(text_input)
outputs = bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)

# Neural network layers
l = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1, name="dropout")(outputs['pooled_output'])
l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(l)

# Use inputs and outputs to construct a final model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input], outputs = [l])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics='accuracy') 

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

# Save the entire model as a SavedModel.
!mkdir -p saved_model
model.save('saved_model/my_model')

# my_model directory
ls saved_model

# Contains an assets folder, saved_model.pb, and variables folder.
ls saved_model/my_model
```